# Wicket localized value in data-original-title

Tags: wicket, wicket-1.6, wicket-6

Is it possible to plave value from properties file into tag parameter with wicket:message without using java.
For example i have the following element `<i class="ico ico-filter-code" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title=""
               data-original-title="Sime title from properties file"></i>`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you looked at wicket:message?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to do it directly like that. A possible workaround would be populating the parameter using javascript, which sources the data from wicket:message.

Comment: There is. See this link: http://pushinginertia.com/2011/08/wicket-internationalization-html-tag-wicket-message/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(In case the links die, here a full blown answer, rep should go to bert as his first comment is corrert :) )

You should use `wicket:message` 
For example:

```
<input
  type="submit"
  wicket:message="name:InputName,title:InputTitle"
/>
```

Will end up as:

```
<input type="submit" name="..." title="...">
```

Where the dots are filled from the propertyFile.

See also the [Wicket documentation on i18n](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Everything+about+Wicket+internationalization)